# Function for identifying graphic/file or archive file by their filename in C

Tags: c

I want to check if a file is graphic, image or archive file by using the following code:

```
int check_ext(const char *name)     
{
    char *extension, *n;
    n=strdup(name);
    extension=strtok(n,".");
    char i1[]="jpeg", i2[]="gif", i3[]="bmp", i4[]="tiff", i5[]="png", i6[]="jpg";
    char a1[]="a", a2[]="ar", a3[]="sbx", a4[]="cpio", a5[]="tar", a6[]="shar", a7[]="LBR", a8[]="iso", a9[]="lbr", a10[]="mar";

    if(strncmp(extension,i1,4)==0 || strncmp(extension,i2,3)==0
        || strncmp(extension,i3,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,i4,4)==0
        || strncmp(extension,i5,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,i6,3)==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strncmp(extension,a1,1)==0 || strncmp(extension,a2,2)==0
        || strncmp(extension,a3,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,a4,4)==0
        || strncmp(extension,a5,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,a6,4)==0
        || strncmp(extension,a7,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,a8,3)==0
        || strncmp(extension,a9,3)==0 || strncmp(extension,a10,3)==0)
    { 
        return 2;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

But I am not able to get the desired result. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: First of all I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. Then also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to tell us the input you give the function, and the expected and actual result of it. Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us as well.

Comment: Might also want to include an example of what the expected output is and what you are getting instead. Also... study binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a simple problem that could have easily been identified if you'd checked out the code in a debugger. The issue is ultimately down to this line of code.

```
extension=strtok(n,".");
```

What it's doing is splitting up the filename by fullstops. It replaces the first fullstop it finds with `'\0'` and returns the first "token". So if for example, your filename is "picture.jpg", `extension` after this function call will contain "picture". Not "jpg" as you're probably expecting. You need to keep calling `strtok(NULL,".")` until you found the last token.

An easier way to do what you're trying to do is to use `strrchr`. It will find the last occurrence of a character in a string so if you had this

```
extension=strrchr(n,'.');
```

it would point to ".jpg". If there was no fullstop at all in the string, it'd return `NULL`. So you should next check for that because `strncmp` won't be happy if it gets a `NULL`. If it isn't `NULL` you can increment the string so that it points at the character after the fullstop.

```
if (extension==NULL)
  {
  return 0;
  }
extension++;
```

That said, there's absolutely no reason to use `strncmp` in this case and in fact it'll cause incorrect classifications. For example if `extension` is "art" - `strncmp("art","a",1)==0` is `true` where as `strcmp("art","a")==0` isn't because it's also taking into account the length of both strings and since you know that `extension` is pointing at the file extension, it should be an exact match.